# No puedo exportar un apk en IONIC 5.4.10 Error Gradle

Tags: java, android, ionic

tengo un problema al ejecutar el comando `ionic cordova build android` , me da el error de abajo, ya tengo instalado java, node, android studio, Gradle lo trae el mismo ANDROID STUDIO pero al ejecutar el comando me dice que por favor instale el Andorid STUDIO pero ya está instalado!! por favor su ayuda.

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\LuisLamos\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por el error, pareciera que el comando build no puede encontrar el Gradle, lo cual muy probablemente se deba a que no está incluido en la variable de entorno PATH.

Para agregarla:

- En el explorador de archivos, click derecho en PC
- Propiedades, Propiedades Avanzadas de sistema
- Variables de Entorno.

Ahi, dentro de las variables de Sistema, buscar la que se llama **PATH**, y agregar una nueva entrada con la ruta a la carpeta **bin** de **Gradle**. Por

ejemplo:

> C:\Gradle\gradle-6.0.1\bin

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funciono pero reinstalando todo, o sea tuve que desinstalar node, android studio, java, gradle etc, y cambiar la ruta tambien de GRADLE dentro de ANDROID STUDIO para que no use la configuracion "recomendada" Muchas gracias amigo.